# What is the difference between .pop and .split in python?

Tags: python

What is the difference between .pop() and .split() in python? How are they used?

Comment: Good start would be a documentation on this:https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Comment: For details with example on split function you can check: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm and for pop function: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_pop.htm

Comment: Luckily the documentation that exists is excellent, take a look at the above links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.pop omits an item from a list.

```
lst=['a','b','c','d']
# to omit 'b' from the list we use .pop
lst.pop(1)
print(lst)
# lst=['a','c','d']
```

the .split function however, splits a string into a list containing the string's items.

```
a="hello world"
a.split()
['hello', 'world']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bruno@fritzbee:~$ python

Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help(list.pop)
Help on method_descriptor:

pop(...)
    L.pop([index]) -> item -- remove and return item at index (default last).
    Raises IndexError if list is empty or index is out of range.
(END)
    >>> l = list("abcd")
>>> print l
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> x = l.pop()
>>> print x
d
>>> print l
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> y = l.pop(0)
>>> print y
a
>>> print l
['b', 'c']
>>> 
>>> help(str.split)
Help on method_descriptor:

split(...)
    S.split([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings

    Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the
    delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
    splits are done. If sep is not specified or is None, any
    whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are removed
    from the result.

>>> sentence = "this is an example"
>>> words = sentence.split()
>>> print words
['this', 'is', 'an', 'example']
>>> row = "a,b,c,d"
>>> row.split(',')
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> querystring = "a=1&foo=bar&baaz=42"
>>> args = dict(p.split("=") for p in querystring.split("&"))
>>> print args
{'a': '1', 'baaz': '42', 'foo': 'bar'}
>>>
```